# Power BI Visualization

Tags: visualization, powerbi

Is it possible to create Power BI plots and data visualisations from data sets programmatically? I am wanting to use a csv file and create a chart on the fly. I couldn't really find much information online about doing this.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried it with R yet? I guess that could be done that way?

Comment: No time for full answer but: I'm not sure whether this matches your scenario, but you can embed Power BI in your apps using APIs. Power BI Embedded is a way of doing this that is being deprecated, so don't start down that road, use the new way!

Answer (score 1):

Power BI supports R integration for data science and prediction. You may create a data frame and use csv data to do your analysis.

https://powerbi.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/powerbi-desktop-r-scripts/

http://www.r-tutor.com/r-introduction/data-frame/data-import

Answer (score -1):

Yes you can, Microsoft has provided very good documentation for Custom Visuals.
Along side, to be specific to your question, you can use d3 library to work around with your csv file.

Note: Microsoft has deprecated the Power BI playground feature so you need to go through the documentation provided to create custom visual via CLI. Also a lot of online tutorials are based on Power BI playground, so make sure your read the documentation.

https://github.com/Microsoft/PowerBI-Visuals/

Comment: I don't think the questioner asked about making new types of charts and visuals, only to take the data from a dataset and chart it.